# Overriding the marginality constraint in dredge from Mumln R-package

Tags: r, mixed-models, nlme

Quick question - is there any possible way of overriding the "marginality constraint" that is imposed by default using ***dredge*** in the [MuMln R-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/MuMIn/MuMIn.pdf)?

I am wanting to force ***dredge*** to consider all possible regression subsets, irrespective of whether interactions are (or are not) present with their corresponding main-effects...

Thank you guys in advance!